# Python: where to handle custom exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

import colorama

class DirectoryExistsError(BaseExceptions):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        log_msg = msg
        print_msg = f"{colorama.Fore.RED}{msg}"
        log_and_print(
            level="critical", log_msg=log_msg, print_msg=print_msg
        )
        sys.exit()

if not Path('some/path').exists():
  raise DirectoryExistsError("message")
```

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

import colorama

class DirectoryExistsError(BaseExceptions):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

if not Path('some/path').exists():
    try:
        raise DirectoryExistsError("message")
    except DirectoryExistsError as e:
        log_msg = e.msg
        print_msg = f"{colorama.Fore.RED}{e.msg}"
        log_and_print(
            level="critical", log_msg=log_msg, print_msg=print_msg
        )
        sys.exit()
```

Between these two example codes, which one should be used? And what would the argument against the other one be? Right now, I'm using the first example.
**My reasoning for using the first example:**
I expect the same code to be ran every time that custom exception is encountered/raised.

Comment: Use the first one, of course. It can reduce a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Both options are terrible. Neither of these options is how exception handling should be done.

Comment: If you want to log a message and exit, write a function that logs a message and exits. Don't raise an exception and then immediately catch it on the next line, or write a class whose `__init__` ends the program.

Comment: No, the code above is just an example. The actual `raise` statement will be deep in some method hierarchy. And what use would Exceptions serve if I just created a function for every exception? "class whose `__init__` ends the program" -> is that not what the first option is doing?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps my sentence structure was unclear. Don't write a class whose `__init__` ends the program.

Comment: "And what use would Exceptions serve if I just created a function for every exception?" - it looks to me like you only need one function. No matter how many different errors you want to handle this way, you only need one function, because the handling is the same.

Comment: If your code has a line `raise Something`, people are going to expect that line to raise the thing it says it's raising. Making it do something completely different from what it says it's doing is terrible for code comprehensibility and maintainability.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, oh you meant it that way. "people are going to expect that line to raise the thing it says it's raising" -> if my understanding of this statement is not mistaken, you're talking about doing stuff in the `__init__`? If so, that totally makes sense.

Comment: I would like to ask upon that, is it fine if I create a separate module/file to handle exceptions? Since I have a lot of exceptions to catch, I feel like it will litter my main file.